# How to cancel or delay a scheduled parachain runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime-upgrade

I would like to know if there is a way to cancel or delay a runtime upgrade already scheduled by a parachain with the relay chain soon about to send the upgrade_go_ahead_signal.

It is fairly easy to block upgrades from being scheduled.
However when trying to block scheduled upgrade by ignoring the relaychain's upgrade_go_ahead_signal, the parachain halts.

Thank you.
Please let me know if any information is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way to cancel a scheduled upgrade. And yes, ignoring the go ahead signal will not change anything. This go ahead signal is the signal to the parachain to apply the runtime, so that with the next block it should use the new runtime. The relay chain is doing the same, as for validation and block building you obviously need to use the same runtime. If you block the signal on the parachain, you only block applying the runtime upgrade on the parachain but not on the relay chain itself.